# Combo Core Data Fetch

Tags: core-data, entity-relationship, nspredicate

I have two types of entities: `Subject`s and `Correspondent`s. They're both related to each other via a to-many relationship. I want to have a single `fetchRequest` that I can pass to a `NSFetchedResultsController` which will have it return:

1. All of the `subject`s which have more than one `correspondent`.
2. All of the `correspondent`s which have `subject`s that only they are apart of.

After trying a variety of things, I decided that it's not possible to make a single fetch that returns both `Subject`s and `Correspondent`s, so I turned to StackOverflow and found someone else suggesting that you have a single entity which does nothing more than have relationships with the two entities you'd like to return.

So I created a third type of entity, which I called `Folder`s, which each have an optional to-one relationship with a `Subject` and a `Correspondent`. It also has two attributes, `hasCorrespondent` and `hasSubject`, which are booleans keeping track of whether `Subject` or `Correspondent` are set.

So I wrote this predicate which returns the `Folder` entities:

```
(hasCorrespondent == 1 AND ANY correspondent.subjects.correspondents.@count == 1)
OR
(hasSubject == 1 AND subject.correspondents.@count >= 1)
```

The issue with this is I'm getting an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Unsupported function expression count:(correspondent.subjects.correspondents)
```

So, any suggestions as to what I'm doing incorrectly? How can I accomplish what I'd like? Are there any additional details I should share?

---

**UPDATE**

With Martin's suggestion, I changed the offending portion to this:

```
SUBQUERY(correspondent.subjects, $s, $s.correspondents.@count == 1).@count > 0
```

But that generated a new error:

```
Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one;
failed to handle $s.correspondents.@count
```

After googling around, I found suggestions to add a check that the collection being enumerated over had at least one object, but modifying the offending line to this didn't change my error messages (so as far as I can tell it did nothing):

```
correspondent.subjects.@count > 0 AND
SUBQUERY(correspondent.subjects, $s, $s.correspondents.@count == 1).@count > 0
```

Comment: Everything I find keeps saying that this error pertains to using sort descriptors, but this is a fetch, not a sort...

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer does not work and I could not figure a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I created an additional field **countSubentity**. And when add/remove subentity change this field. And predicate looks:

> [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(subcategories, $s,
>   $s.countSubentity > 0).@count > 0"];

Answer (score 0):

This work around has been less than ideal, but it seems to get the job done:
1 - I added an attribute to subject called count.
2 - I set (part of) my expression to
    ANY correspondent.subjects.count == 1
Note that no SUBQUERY() was necessary for this workaround.
3 - Everytime I modify a subject's correspondents set, I run
    subject.count = @(subject.correspondents.count);

I'm still hoping for a better solution and will be happy to mark any (working) better solution as correct.